# Simple question about circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The picture below shows a page of my mechanics (M2) textbook. At the top of this page, you'll see that it says that 
"a=-ω^2r".

Why is it then that all the answers to the question in exercise 6B (also on the page in the picture attached) are positive? Surely the minus sign in the equation for 'a' should man that all the answers should be negative?

[image: Page from M2 textbook]

Unfortunately, I am the only person in my Further Maths class who doesn't do physics, so this mechanics module has been quite difficult for me. This is probably therefore a really stupid question... but oh well; better to ask than to not know.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise 6B asks for the **magnitude** of the acceleration. The magnitude of any vector, including acceleration, is a nonnegative number. The idea is that it's the "length" of a vector. Equation [4] in your book gets at this, but not as explicitly as it could.

As a mathematical aside, don't assume that a negative sign in front of some expression means the entire quantity is negative; the thing to the right of the negative sign could be negative itself. Besides, a vector with a negative out in front doesn't really mean it's negative; it just means that the *directions* two vectors are opposite. For your particular case, it means the vector $\vec{a}$ and the vector $\omega^2 \vec{r}$ are in opposite directions. Though I'll admit it is sometimes convenient and common place to speak of "negative" vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the help.   

Regarding what you've said about the negative sign not necessarily making the entire quantity negative; it would in this case? It would be impossible to end up with a positive answer unless you were using imaginary numbers, as you could not have a negative radius?

Comment: The vector $\vec{r}$ in that equation has a direction associated with it. It is possible that this vector points in the "negative" direction already.